# Creating an own SocketChannel in Java

Tags: java, sockets, networking, socketchannel

I am currently working on a small Networking - Library and trying to unite a few socket related classes like e.g. Socket, SocketChannel, DatagramSocket, DatagramSocketChannel, so that the user is able to implement his own Sockets really simple.

The implementation of an own socket should be done by just inheriting from a super - class giving some methods to implement. Thus the methods implemented are ready to be passed on to a class, that inherits the e.g. `SocketImpl` - Class. The implemented methods will be put into the corresponding methods of the `SocketImpl` subclass, so that a final call to the `Socket.setSocketImplFactory` function would finish off the whole procedure.

But this only works for the Socket and DatagramSocket classes because of them having the static methods `Socket.setSocketImplFactory` and `DatagramSocket.setDatagramSocketImplFactory`.

Now I have seen that the NIO Sockets like `SocketChannel` and `DatagramSocketChannel` have a method `socket()` that returns either a `Socket` or a `DatagramSocket`.

So my final questions after the long journey are: In how far would a call to the `Socket.setSocketImplFactory`, given a custom `SocketImplFactory`, affect the `Socket` returned by the `SocketChannel::socket` method? Is it possible to customize a `SocketChannel` by just "manipulating" the `Socket` returned by the `socket()` method?